# Locking liquidity on pancake, trading fees

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap

I want to lock the liquidity tokens (LP), so people trust more my token.

My concern: So, when you hold the LP tokens in your wallet, you will get trading fees when people trade in your liquidity pool, how will I receive the trading fees from my liquidity pool if I locked the LP tokens and i'm not holding them?

Comment: You wont, the locked LPs will grow as expected but thats all.

Comment: So, who is collecting trading fees?

Comment: The address where the locked tokens are (im assuming the dead address)

Comment: No, I'm not talking about burning the LP tokens, I'm talking about using a service that blocks the LP tokens for a period of time dxsale for example